# Notify about service running

Tags: android, service

I have a service running that I stop with `stopSelf`.

I want an icon to be shown in the icon bar on the top of the window while the service is running, something that I can start for instance in `handleMessage` and stop before `stopSelf`.

What do you recommend?

Comment: It's called a notification - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: You should use startForegroung method of service class with particular notification ID which u want to show

Comment: @MarkKeen I used the notification. Thanks mate.